# Проблема с регистрацией callback_query хендлера aiogram3

Tags: python, callback, aiogram-3.x, handlers

Не понимаю, регистрирую хендлер, но он не срабатывает (код не заходит в функцию select_macbook)

```
dp.callback_query.register(select_macbook, F.data.startswith("macbook_"))
```

Вот переменная с клавиатурой и сама функция select_macbook:

```
select_macbook_button = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
[
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="MacBook1", callback_data="macbook_1"),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="MacBook2", callback_data="macbook_2"),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="MacBook3", callback_data="macbook_3")
],
[
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="Link", url="https://google.com")
],
[
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="Profile", url="tg://user?id=2067289122")
]
])


async def select_macbook(call: CallbackQuery, bot: Bot):
    model = call.data.split("_")[1]
    await call.message.answer(f"Ты выбрал MacBook {model}")
    await call.answer()
```